# How to convert an array of number base 10 to base 16 use array_map and intval?

Tags: php, callback, callable, array-map

I try to convert an array of number to base 16 use `intval` and I want learn how to pass second argument to interval, in default `intval` use base 10.

```
array_map('intval', [1, 2, "12", "15" , "99"]);
```

Before I search in google and read php.net document but can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own anonymous function:

```
array_map(function ($value) { return intval($value, 16); }, [1, 2, "12", "15", "99"]);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/PoFZN**

Comment: Thanks Jeto  Soleve my problem with `use` to send more parameters
    $base = 16;  array_map(function($value) use ($base) { return intval($value, $base); }, [1, 2, "12", "15", "99"])

Comment: @Jeto I think this is incorrect, doesn't this treat the value as already in base 16 ? Change `intval` to `base_convert` and you are good.

Comment: @msg What do you mean "already in base 16"? This just gets the integer value of every item in the array, using base 16. Unless I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @AliYousefi He wants to convert **from** base 10 **to** base 16. `intval` returns a number in base 10.

Comment: @msg You're right, that was worded wrongly. If he does want to convert, then `base_convert` sounds right, but from his opening post he just wanted a way to pass that second arg to `intval`, hence this answer.

Comment: Thanks @msg And @jeto    
I learn many things , `array_map` work on one by one element and use `base_convert` to convert base 10 to 16.  And for send parameter to callback should use anonymous function.  

    array_map(
      function($value) use($from, $to) { 
        return base_convert($value, $from, $to);
      },
      [1, 2, "12", "15", "99"]
    )